# ionic header, how to use whole screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

The following is my ionic header code. I have the SVG in the ion-item element, which has ion-no-padding class.

Somehow, there is still space to the right, and a line below. Any hints as to why? I am quite new at ionic, so spending a lot of time in docs.

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-avatar slot="end">
      <img src="assets/profile.jpg">
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-button fill="clear" color="light">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <div class="ion-padding-start ion-padding-bottom">
      <ion-label>
        <h2>Choose a Car</h2>
      </ion-label>

      <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
        <ion-col size="10">
          <ion-searchbar placeholder="Oman, Muscat" searchIcon="location-outline"></ion-searchbar>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="2">
          <ion-button color="light" fill="clear">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="options-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
 
    </div>

        </ion-item>
 <ion-item expandable=true class="ion-no-padding">
    <svg style="pointer-events: none" class="wave" width="100%" height="50px" preserveAspectRatio="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 75">
            <defs>
              <svg:style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
        .a {fill: none}.b {clip-path: url(#a)}.c,.d {fill: hsla(234, 20%, 95%, 1)}.d {opacity: 0.5;isolation: isolate;}
         ]]>
    </svg:style>
    <clipPath id="a"><rect class="a" width="1920" height="75"></rect></clipPath></defs>
            <g class="b"><path class="c" d="M1963,327H-105V65A2647.49,2647.49,0,0,1,431,19c217.7,3.5,239.6,30.8,470,36,297.3,6.7,367.5-36.2,642-28a2511.41,2511.41,0,0,1,420,48"> </path> </g>
            <g class="b"><path class="d" d="M-127,404H1963V44c-140.1-28-343.3-46.7-566,22-75.5,23.3-118.5,45.9-162,64-48.6,20.2-404.7,128-784,0C355.2,97.7,341.6,78.3,235,50,86.6,10.6-41.8,6.9-127,10"> </path> </g>
            <g class="b"><path class="d" d="M1979,462-155,446V106C251.8,20.2,576.6,15.9,805,30c167.4,10.3,322.3,32.9,680,56,207,13.4,378,20.3,494,24"> </path></g>
            <g class="b"><path class="d" d="M1998,484H-243V100c445.8,26.8,794.2-4.1,1035-39,141-20.4,231.1-40.1,378-45,349.6-11.6,636.7,73.8,828,150"></path></g>
        </svg>
 </ion-item>
</ion-header>
```

[image: header screenshot]

Comment: lines="none" got rid of the line at bottom. Only thing is the space on the right

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-item  {
  --inner-padding-end:0px
}
```

I found the inner-padding was 16px, affecting the ion-item in the header. Problem solved.